# SparkLauncher constructor not working

Tags: apache-spark, spark-launcher

I need to run a Spark job from thread launched from a Web Application running on Liberty (17.0.0.2). This is deployed on a Docker container.

I am able to get this working by launching the spark (2.2.0) job through spark-submit script launched from the java code. However, I want to remove the script invocation and use SparkLauncher. When I do this, the code hangs on SparkLauncher constructor. The constructor does not return anything blocking the whole work. I don't see logs after the invocation of the constructor in code below.

```
private static Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    env.put("SPARK_HOME", "/Spark");
    env.put("JAVA_HOME", "/opt/ibm/java-x86_64-80/jre");
    env.put("SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND","1");
}
private static final String SPARK_MASTER_URL = "local[*]";

public SparkAppHandle launch(String appName, String appJar, String sparkClass, String[] args)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    logger.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS, "launch", " About to create SparkLauncher ");
    SparkLauncher launchPad = new SparkLauncher(env);

    logger.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS, "launch", " About to set Spark App Name ");
    launchPad = launchPad.setAppName(appName);
```

Any clue on how to debug this further? I could not find logs with any information to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was a class path issue; some jars were missing. However, somehow there was no information in the log to debug this, very strange. After ensuring all relevant jars in the classpath it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the launch method of SparkLauncher ? It would return Process, and you need to capture the output of this process to see what's going on

Comment: No, I am not using **launch** but **startApplication**

Comment: startApplication will also launch another process, call redirectOutput method to redirect the process output